# I have an interview I'm not prepared to go to, can I ask for a reschedule?

Tags: interviewing

When I called the employer **yesterday** she asked me if I could show up **today** for an interview so I agreed right away but to be honest I didn't think it through at the moment. I'm totally unprepared. Is it possible for me to ask her to reschedule because of such reason? And do I have to call before the time of appointment? Would it make it worse if I called her right at the time of appointment or a few minutes late?

Comment: I guess it was because I am so inexperienced with job searches (and most things in life to be perfectly honest), and so desperate for a job that when it piqued a little of my interest I didn't think twice before jumping the gun? Although I did a little thinking that went like "be brave! man up and just call her you coward!" I'm just trying to begin dragging myself our of the shell, putting myself out there, starting with applying for jobs even though I know I won't have much chance getting hired, picking up bit by bit of experience on job interviews and stuff.

Comment: why are you unprepared? If they're willing to interview you immediately I wouldn't think it's a high level job that you'd need to study for. I'd just go in and if there was any issue, I'd just say it was short notice, Many of my interviews have been short notice, if you're confident and know your stuff they're usually ok.

Comment: "Would it make it worse if I called her right at the time of appointment or a few minutes late?" - Yes, this would make things worse. If you want to reschedule for any reason, you should call as soon as realistically possible. For example, if you feel sick in the morning and can't go for that reason, you ought to let them know the same morning.

Comment: I agree with Killsi, what kind of preparation do you need?  Just go to the interview.

Answer (score 12):

> I'm totally unprepared. Is it possible for me to ask her to reschedule
>   because of such reason?

Obviously, you know it was a mistake to accept an interview without considering if you could be adequately prepared for it.

It's possible to call right away and ask for the interview to be rescheduled, but it would be foolish to give your reason as "because I'm not prepared". That tells them either that you don't know how to prepare yourself quickly, or that you don't think things through before you speak. Neither of those are appealing attributes for candidates.

Instead, be vague, and say something along the lines of "I'm really sorry, but something came up at the last minute, and I have to reschedule." Then consider their next proposed interview date/time more carefully.

> And do I have to call before the time of appointment? Would it make it
>   worse if I called her right at the time of appointment or a few
>   minutes late?

It's far worse to wait until the time of the appointment. When I schedule an interview, I have to block time out of my calendar, and often time out of others' calendars as well. When a candidate is a no-show, or cancels right at the last minute, that's a huge red flag (and often gets them crossed off the list immediately).

Don't wait. Call now and reschedule. Be apologetic and hope for the best.

Comment: Do you mean `interviwee` (the person apply for the job) not `interviewer` (the person conducting the interview). ~ When an *interviewer* is a no-show...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm totally unprepared.

While this doesn't help you right now (I'll get to the specifics in a moment), you need to consider the impact of this.

You should always be prepared to have an interview the following day.  If you **need** to do more than a couple hours of prep before an interview, you should consider whether or not you're qualified for the position to which you're applying. If not, that's ok. There's no shame in that. Aside from brushing up on key terminologies and definitions, prep time for an interview should focus on the company you're interviewing with so you can demonstrate both interest as well as initiative in not waiting to be told about their company by the interviewer.

> Is it possible for me to ask her to reschedule because of such reason? 
>   It is, but I would wonder if you'd be prepared if it were the next day. Many people will expect you to be more prepared if you delay it because the thinking is, "he had an extra day to look that up"

Don't make the mistake of telling her that though. A vague answer will work and people don't tend to delve into the reasons.  "I had something come up that I absolutely have to take care of" followed by profuse apologies.  There's no guarantee that she's going to believe you and it could still have a negative effect.

> And do I have to call before the time of appointment? Would it make it worse if I called her right at the time of appointment or a few minutes late?

If you don't call well before the appointment for a non-emergency cancellation, you're sending the message that her time isn't important. She's set apart an hour (or more) of her day for you and you've just thrown it away when she could have scheduled something else in that time.

If you ever have to reschedule an interview, do it as early as possible, apologize profusely and emphasize how grateful you are for the opportunity and how much you look forward to meeting with her.

Calling right before the appointment time or even worse, after you should have been there is always bad. Reasonable excuses (emergency or going to be late because of traffic) are better, but still can leave a bad taste.